# Getting ERROR: You need to send a valid key to execute this file when running Cron

Tags: wordpress, cron-job, scheduling

When I run my cron job, wget -O - -q -t 1 domain.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXXXX

When I use this link in my browser it works just fine no issue, so the key is valid. I get the same error when running GET domain.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXXXX

I can't seem to use single quotes or it stops running altogether. A FQDN and I get a JSON error in the cron setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without quotes around the URL, your shell may interpret the '&' character as a request to run a command in the background:

```
$ wget -O - -q -t 1 none.such/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXXXX
[1] 9887
[2] 9888
$ jobs
[1]-  Exit 4                  wget -O - -q -t 1 none.such/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX
[2]+  Done                    pass=XXX
$
```

Here it uses the URL up to but not including the first '&', thus missing the `pass` and `key` parameters. Enclosing the URL in quotes should resolve this:

```
$ wget -O - -q -t 1 'none.such/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXXXX'
$
```

You say this didn't work for you, could you provide details of what command you tried and what the result was?

Comment: When I used quotes like this GET 'domain.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXX&pass=XXX&key=XXXXX'

Nothing happens. Job does not run. I do not get an email. I let it sit through 3 cycles last night and it never ran once.

Comment: Tiffany - can you please clarify whether you're running this command directly on a command line when you test?  Or are you using your webhost's control panel?  If the latter, then there may be a security setting on the webhost's control panel.  If you're testing directly on the command line, please show the output of the command when you use the single quotes?

Comment: I am running it on CPanel

Answer (score 0):

This was a permissions issue with my webhost like davejenx suggested. Quick fix via support chat.